# Where are recent Warning popups logged?

Tags: wordpress

CiviCRM has certain post-installation checks where you get displayed warnings on your webadmin dashboard, for instance on missing file permissions for directories. But when you click them away they are gone. I informed my Admin about them, but there was no way to tell him the exact content of the warnings.

a) Are past warnings logged somewhere?
b) How do we manually check our installations again?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually check the warnings by calling the `System.check` API. There are a couple ways to do this:

- Navigate to `Help => Developer => API Explorer`. Choose `Entity`=`System` and `Action`=`check`.
- If you use Drupal's `drush` or WordPress's `wp-cli`, then you can run `drush cvapi system.check` or `wp civicrm api system.check`.

Using the API Explorer is probably a bit better in this case because it will run the check with you web server's PHP runtime. In some edge-cases, the web and CLI runtimes may be slightly different.